# Socket.IO error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String okhttp3.MediaType.toString()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, node.js, okhttp

I try to connect my android app to nodeJs server but it's not working... I get the error **Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String okhttp3.MediaType.toString()' on a null object reference**

Here is my nodeJs server code

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080),
dns = require('dns'),
express = require('express'),
mysql = require('mysql'),
interval = 2000,
google = 'www.google.com';

var connect = mysql.createClient({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'database'
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(socket);
})
```

And this is my Java code...

```
//importing socket.io dependencies
import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;

//initializing socket variable
static Socket socket;

try {
    socket = IO.socket(socketUrl);
    socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    socket.emit("connected", userId);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    socket.connect();
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And this is my LOG

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: com.pixtanta.android, PID: 26214
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String okhttp3.MediaType.toString()' on a null object reference
        at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR$Request.onLoad(PollingXHR.java:271)
        at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR$Request.access$700(PollingXHR.java:148)
        at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR$Request$1.onResponse(PollingXHR.java:232)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

I am still new to Android Studio and Java... Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: is socketUrl defined? The error would seem to say that 'socketUrl' is not defined, so when it tries to connect to the socket server its null

Comment: Yes... socketUrl is defined as `http://192.168.**.0:8080` which is my PC's IP address. I also tried using `http://10.0.2.2:8080` as my socketUrl but I still get the same error

Comment: That seems to be an internal network IP address, are you sure the android app is able to access that URL? Also it could be that its not https as Android has been cracking down on unsecure connections like that

Comment: It's not an internal Network IP address... As both IPs work on my Android emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a bug fix for this in the library you are using

https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-client-java/commit/6f065b7a62603730979d43cec71af0046ca4ab7c#diff-4095582e8c038519a759817bf31dbfd7686a4f58942ad00daaf8201d5f936a3a

Comment: I have checked the link and it seems that's the problem... But it's a Read Only file so I can't edit it. I also try to use the latest okhttp3 library but no changes in the file. Do you know how I can edit the file?

Comment: upgrade to 2.0.0


    <groupId>io.socket</groupId>
    <artifactId>engine.io-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>